# How to implement my code in MVC Java?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jframe, hierarchy

I am making a game which will have three games implemented in it. I started off my code in a single class, now that I want to move it around into a MVC format I am having errors. I started off with writing all the code in GameView Class, I now want to move some of the code from this class to a SView Class. The problem is that I have intialised the JFrame in GameView class and it cannot find the variable frame when I move my code to SView class. So then I have been told to make it into a panel and then move it but it's just messing up my game.

Answer (score 1):

You have to organize things a little differently. Some things to consider:

- Is `GameView` your main window? Make it so `GameView extends JFrame`.
- Is `SView` a panel? Make it so `SView extends Panel`.

Another thing to think about: `SView` is some panel that you want to add to your `GameView`, but it's not the responsibility of `SView` to add *itself*. Instead, simply instantiate and assemble these components somewhere outside both of these classes, f.e.:

```
GameView gameView = new GameView();
gameView.add(new SView());
```

You could also have `GameView` add a `new SView()` in its constructor code instead.

Anyway, the main point here is that a component should not concern itself with adding itself to its parent, just with creating its own content/children.

Good luck.

Comment: I see no good reason in any of the original poster's code above for a class to extend JFrame or JPanel.

Comment: What should I do with the last line? It has got frame in the parameter.                                    panel.setLocation((frame.getWidth()-panel.getWidth())/2, 80);

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- The main GUI would use a CardLayout so you can swap JPanels easily.
- The main function of the select game menu will be to swap JPanels, so the game selected is visualized and then initialize the selected game.
- Work on each game individually. Gear each individual game class towards produding a JPanel to hold the game. Give each game class a main method for testing that would create a JFrame, create a game class instance, place the instance's JPanel into the JFrame, initialize the game and display it.
- Once the game is working on its own, try adding it to your larger GUI, the one that can show multiple games.
- Consider having each game class implement a common interface for common functionality. For example you could give the interface an initialize() method that each game class would override.
- Each game class would need to be MVC-based so that it has a model, a control class(es) to interact with the model and a view class that displays the state of the model on the JPanel as noted above.

Comment: +1 Excellent design advice; [`MainPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) is an example of point three. You can use any number of instances to prototype your larger GUI.

Comment: @trashgod: thanks. Here's my link for an example of MVC: [MVC_ProgressBarThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533497/mvc-progress-bar-threading/5533581#5533581)

Comment: Good [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533497/mvc-progress-bar-threading/5533581#5533581); I cited it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) as a way to implement the observer pattern. Don't hesitate to edit anything of mine as the need arises.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I replied. My bad. My question was I dont understand the CardLayout part, how does it work?

Comment: @UmzzMo: Check out [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), and in fact check out all of the Swing tutorials found there.