# Unexpected behavior of Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I came across this interesting situation while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183212/return-a-variable-value-to-main-on-button-click/12183457#12183457).

Try this piece of poorly designed code -

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class abc extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

boolean button_clicked = false;
JButton b1;

abc(){
    this.setSize (400, 400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.createUI();
}

void createUI(){
    this.setLayout(null);
    b1 = new JButton("Click here");
    b1.setSize(110,30);
    b1.setLocation(10,210);
    this.add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
}

public boolean isButton_clicked()
{
    return button_clicked;
}

public void setButton_clicked(boolean button_clicked) {
    this.button_clicked = button_clicked;
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    button_clicked = true;
}

}
```

Here's the main method.

```
class tempMain extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    abc temp = new abc();
    temp.setVisible(true);
    while(true)
    {
    //  Thread.sleep(200);
        if(temp.isButton_clicked())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
            temp.setButton_clicked(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I ran this on my Windows 7 machine, nothing happened for at least about a minute (I didn't wait after that) after I clicked the button.

Now, just make one small change -

```
  Thread.sleep(200); // uncomment this from the main.
```

And surprisingly, it works and a JOptionPane message is displayed. Why is the message not displayed the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And surprisingly, it works and a JOptionPane message is displayed. Why is the message not displayed the first time?

`button_clicked` is not marked as `volatile` and is being updated from a different thread than the main thread.  Since the call-back is made from the event handler thread, the main thread will not see the update unless `button_clicked` is defined as a `volatile boolean`.  Putting a sleep may allow a memory barrier to be crossed and `button_clicked` to be updated in the main thread luckily.

Here's some more [reading about volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml) and why it is important when we are dealing with multiple threads.

---

Another issue is that you have an infinite loop which is spewing messages to `System.out`.  This completely blocks after a while because the console can't display lines that fast which stops the checking for the click.

Comment: Update : I removed the System.out.println(). The problem persists even without that.

Comment: Could you please explain - " Since the call-back is made from the event handler thread, the main thread will not see the update" ? As far as I understand, the main is calling a method of the abc class and should always be able to get the latest value of button_clicked.

Comment: But we are talking about multiple threads that can be running on multiple processors, each with their own memory caches.  Java needs to be told that `button_clicked` needs to be synchronized between the threads.  Here's some reading: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml