# Java API returning progress to client

Tags: java, swing, jar, progress

I am writing a `java library ( jar )` that contains numerous API's that will be called by an external software . One of the  API will be a blocking API and will be performing an operation that can be quite lengthy .

I want a way to be able to provide regular feedback ( % completion ) of the operation to the client .

`NOTE` Since its a library I cannot use the Java Swing mechanism of a progress bar to get and update a progress percent . Everything i search somehow leads to that .

Is there anyway to do this ?

```
Answer Update
```

Many thanks to all who posted answers . It helped me gain a grasp . I exposed the following interfaces on my jar . The client worker thread will register and listen for my progress updates . Then it will update the progress bar accordingly .

```
void LongAPI(){
while{
do work ; 
fireprogress();
     }
}
public void addProgressListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);

}

public void removeProgressListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

private void fireProgress(double pourcent) {
    for (Listener listener : listeners) {
        listener.setProgress(pourcent);
    }
}
```

The `Listener` is an abstract interface that all clients much implement . It has the setProgress property using which the client can update its UI as it wishes .

Comment: *"I want a way to be able to provide regular feedback ( % completion ) of the operation to the client"*  Does the API actually provide any means to query the completion?  If so, it should be easy to use that from within a `SwingWorker` to update a progress bar.  If not, the best you can do is an indeterminate progress bar.  Either way it leads back to `JProgressBar`.  So why is it not suitable?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: My guess -- it's not suitable in the observed class, which does make sense since the observer will likely be displaying the data. It smells like all he needs is a good observer design pattern.

Comment: @rockstar to hold EDT rulles, because `regular feedback ( % completion...` is only about your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would give it a PropertyChangeSupport object as well as `addPropertyChangeListener(...)` and `removePropertyChangeListener(...)` methods. Internally, I'd create *bound* properties with setters that fire the support object. This way external libraries can be notified in a standard way that the property of interest has changed. If it is a Swing based library, consider using specifically a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object so that all PropertyChangeListeners that have been added to the support object are notified on the Swing event thread.

For example, please have a look at the answer to these questions:

- [Java: How to reference GUI components from an AbstractAction object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503673/522444)
- [accessing variables and swing components through different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11171831/522444)

Comment: @rockstar The `SwingWorker` is a good example of this concept

Answer (score 4):

Because you want to give progress to a client you can use a specific model for that.

One approach could be to return a [BoundedRangeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html) to the client.

```
 public BoundedRangeModel getProgressModel();
```

A client can then get it and

- connect it directly to a ui component, e.g. `JProgressBar` or `JSlider` or whatever.
- or connect it to his own model objects and listen to the changes
- or just retrieve the state when the client needs it.

I would prefer the `BoundedRangeModel` over a `PropertyChangeListener`, because a `BoundedRangeModel` provides a [getValueAdjusting()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29) method. The client can ask if the value is adjusting to prevent unnecessary repaints.

Comment: Yes, this would likely be better for binding numeric properties. 1+